# Get ClassTag from within specialized class

Tags: scala, reflection, jvm

When I have a @specialized class, I retain the information about what primitive my type is. Is there a **fast** way to get a `ClassTag[T]`, e.g. to create arrays?

This does not compile, because no ClassTag[T] is available

```
class Foo[@specialized T] {
  def bar: Array[T] = new Array[T]
}
```

This works, but I want to avoid passing the ClassTag

```
class Foo[@specialized T: ClassTag] {
  def bar: Array[T] = new Array[T]
}
```

This works, but is slow:

```
class Foo[@specialized T] {
  def bar: Array[T] = new Array[T]

  implicit def classTag: ClassTag[T] = {
    val name = getClass.getName
    if(name.endsWith("$I$sp") ClassTag.Int
    else if(name.endsWith("$L$sp") ClassTag.Long
    else ??? // you get the idea
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second variant?

Comment: You can not use Foo from a place where you do not have a ClassTag (inside some other generic method). E.g. you want to implement a typeclass such as https://github.com/non/alleycats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/alleycats/Pure.scala

Comment: I guess you are left with the third option then. You could also probably try to look at scala macros. Theoretically it should be possible to inject some kind of flag depending on the `specialized` implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specialization happens later than materialization of ClassTags at typer, so there's the matter of the barn door.

The other issue is that specialization will create double definitions, so it's not trivial to hand-specialize a method in the obvious way.

Here's an attempt to mix-in the specialized method that provides a class tag.

Specialized `f` calls specialized `ct` which is overridden in the trait.

I don't know that the dummy arg to `ct` is necessary to make it specialize; maybe the `ClassTag[A]` result type isn't enough.

```
$ scalam
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import reflect.ClassTag
import reflect.ClassTag

scala> class CT[@specialized(Int) A] {
     |   def ct(a: A): ClassTag[A] = ???
     |   def f: Array[A] = ct(null.asInstanceOf[A]).newArray(1)
     | }
defined class CT

scala> trait CTS { def ct$mcI$sp(i: Int): ClassTag[Int] = reflect.classTag[Int] }
defined trait CTS

scala> (new CT[Int] with CTS).f
res0: Array[Int] = Array(0)
```

Showing specialized invocation:

```
scala> :javap -c -
Compiled from "<console>"
[snip]
      16: invokevirtual #32                 // Method $line16/$read$$iw$$iw$$anon$1.f$mcI$sp:()[I
      19: putfield      #24                 // Field res0:[I
```

Comment: Great. This is *exactly* what I was hoping for. Now the only question is whether I should actually use it.

Comment: Ha. It looks hairy but maybe is OK. Your use case is not odd; but I don't use specialized. It would be nice if you could write, `@specializing(Int) def ct(i: Int) = ???` to supply a hand-crafted method body.